# Impossible to insert EPS graphics files in Powerpoint

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, images, microsoft-powerpoint

I would like to insert EPS files in Microsoft Powerpoint 2016 on latest version of Windows 10 Pro x64.

I followed the instructions delivered by Microsoft in:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2479871/security-settings-for-graphic-filters-for-microsoft-office-365

I modified the registry keys as instructed. I'd like to post an image but I'm not allowed to for the moment by the site.

I double-checked every register entry name and value, everything is definitely ok.

I then rebooted so the new registry values are taken into account.

Finally, when I try to import EPS images, I get:

- when performing "insert/image" and picking an eps image, I get an empty frame with a message "impossible to display the image" (freely translated from French).
- when performing click-and-slide insertion from the file explorer, I get a frame with the icon of the file.

I am quite blocked since all instructions are clear and it seems that I did everything right.

Any idea for fixing that ? Can it be due to recent versions of Windows 10 definitely blocking EPS files importation ?

Thank you in advance for your answers,
Ben.

Comment: Was PPT open while you made the registry changes?  That won't work.  PPT (including hidden instances) must be closed. If you look at the values you changed again, are they what you expected them to be?

Comment: Powerpoint was closed, and when I go back to the registry editor, everything I added is still here.

Comment: OK, then that's not the problem.  You might try checking the steps on my PPTFAQ site; they may be clearer than the MS explanation, which is challenging even to a native English speaker: 
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ01250-I-can-no-longer-insert-EPS-graphics-into-PowerPoint.htm  And somewhere in their explanation they mention that the filter numbers you add to the registry are for the English version of PPT.  It's possible that the French version numbers are different, though I don't know where you'd find them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually based my modifications both on your site and on Microsoft help website. I checked, the french page on the Microsoft website gives exactly the same values as the English one. And that would be strange (even for Microsoft) to change registry values names depending on the language. The base software is exactly the same, the different languages can be seen more like plugins. I'll just keep on not using EPS files I guess

Comment: Are these large EPS files? Can you put an example file up on OneNote/Dropbox/etc?